# Email verif status will not become true except in the vscode i do hot reload

Tags: flutter

I have problem with email verif status. I want if email verif status is true then go to home. I have this if condition in RaisedButton, so if user click the button and email verif status is true, then return to Wrapper.

```
dynamic verifEmail = await _auth.isEmailVerified();
if (verifEmail == true) {
   print('in');
   // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Home.tag);
   return Wrapper();
}
```

this is the code of isEmailVerified()

```
Future<bool> isEmailVerified() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  await user.reload();
  user = await _auth.currentUser();
  return user.isEmailVerified;
}
```

and this is the code of the Wrapper class.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
  return Scaffold(
    body :StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        print('Verif email ' + snapshot.data.isEmailVerified.toString());
        return snapshot.data.isEmailVerified
            ? Home(uidCode: user.uid)
            : VerifEmail(user: snapshot.data);
      }
      else {
        return Authenticate();
      }
    },
  ),
  );
}
}
```

The problem is in the Wrapper class, email verif status will not become true except in the vscode i do hot reload. So i cant go to home page except i do hot reload in the vscode. Please anyone can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the problem is, but if you need to do a Hot Reload, adding a `setState((){})` call somewhere may fix the issue.

Comment: where i must add the setState((){}) ?? I have no idea where to place it.